# Are the connected components of a regular open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ regular open?

Tags: general-topology

A regular open set $O$ is an open set satisfying $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(O))=O$. It may be not connected, for example the union of two (open) disks that are disjoint.

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally connected, so the connected components of an open subset is open.

What is very intuitive to me is that the connected components of a regular open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are also regular open. Is the result true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems so. As you say, the components of a regular open set $U ⊆ ℝ^n$ are open, so even clopen from the point of view of $U$. So if there is anything extra in $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(C))$ for $C$ a component of $U$, it is outside of $U$ and so demonstrating that $U$ itself was not regular open.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!